# Android manifest.json doesn't work

Tags: android, json, google-chrome, web-applications, manifest

Dear StackOverFlowers,

I'm was making a first attempt to start using chrome's webapp manifest.json.

The working project is this: https://bouwman.me/webapp
Stylesheet works fine on chrome android and chrome desktop.

And when I add it to my homescreen the manifest.json works, until the site has been loaden.

The stylesheet doesn't work and the portret mode has the same. The fullsreen does work.

The manifest.json is located at [link to manifest.json](https://bouwman.me/webapp/manifest.json)

Hope someone could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Theo Bouwman

Comment: Your site isn't loading